# Is it possible to apply \regex_count to the contents of a tl variable?

Tags: expl3, count, regex

I tried

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {Hello World}
\int_new:N \l_foo_int
\regex_count:nnN { Hello } {\tl_use:Nn \l_tmpa_tl } \l_foo_int
```

which doesn't work obviously. Could it maybe be achieved with `\regex_count:nVN`?

Comment: you want `V` not `n`  argument to access the value of a variable

Comment: `\regex_count:nVN { Hello } \l_tmpa_tl `

Comment: Unfortunately `\regex_count:nVN  {Hello} \l_tmpa_tl \l_foo_int` raises an undefined control sequence error. I'm using tex live 2023

Comment: Please give a full example, for me `\regex_count:nVN { Hello } { \l_tmpa_tl } \l_foo_int` now has 1 in `\l_foo_int`.

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn  \l_tmpa_tl {Hello World}
\int_new:N \l_foo_int
\regex_count:nVN {Hello} \l_tmpa_tl \l_foo_int

\int_use:N \l_foo_int

\ExplSyntaxOff`

This gives me `\regex_count:nVN` undefined control sequence

Comment: you should update, but you could use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN  {nVN}` to define the V version

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I already have the latest tex live version and tex live 2024 isn't out yet.

Comment: no you are missing an expl3 update that added variants f several commands

Comment: `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks so much.